# How to fetch repeatedly and render updated api data in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, fetch, dom-events

I am trying to render time data from API endpoint http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now
The "currentFileTime" property is constantly changing but renders once on load.
I tried setInterval method to update state but it doesn't work. May be I am making some mistake?

This is App.js:

```
import React , { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: []};
  }

 async componentDidMount(){  
                            this.fetchData();      
                          }

  async fetchData() {
    try { 
          const response = await  fetch('http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now');
          if (!response.ok) {throw Error(response.statusText);}
          const json = await response.json();
          this.setState({ data: json});
          console.log(json);
        }   
    catch (error) {console.log(error);}
  }

  render() {return (<div><h1>worldclockapi.com data (edit App.js)</h1>
                         <li>currentFileTime: {this.state.data.currentFileTime }</li>
              </div> );
            }
}

export default App;
```

How to render and update currentFileTime continuously in react component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is componentDidMount executed only once, after component mounted for the first time, for example if your state changes componentDidMount is not gonna execute again.
in your case i think it's better to use websockets but if u wanna keep useing this api u can use useEffect hook like below:

```
const [temp, setTemp] = useState(0)

useEffect(()=>{
  setIterval(()=>{
    setTemp((prevTemp)=>prevTemp+1)
  }, 2000)
}, [])

useEffect(()=>{
  fetchData()
}, [temp])
```

in the above code we have a temp variable and it's value update every 2 second and every time it gets updated the second useEffect run and the data will fetch and as a result the state's gonna change and element gets updated.

Answer (score 1):

This is using the new hooks. This should solve the problems

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const App  = () => {
const [state, setState] = useState({data: []});

useEffect(()=>{
    fetchData();
}, [state]);

const fetchData =  async () => {
    try {
        const response = await  fetch('http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now');
        if (!response.ok) {throw Error(response.statusText);}
        const json = await response.json();
        setState({ data: json});
        console.log(json);
    }
    catch (error) {console.log(error);}
}

return (<div><h1>worldclockapi.com data (edit App.js)</h1>
<li>currentFileTime: {state.data.currentFileTime }</li>
</div> );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Calling fecthData recursively upon successful data retrieval like below.
And you don't need to put "async" in front of componentDidMount cause you ain't awaiting anything in the method call.

```
  async fetchData() {
    try { 
          const response = await  fetch('http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now');
          if (!response.ok) {throw Error(response.statusText);}
          const json = await response.json();
          this.setState({ data: json});
          console.log(json);

          // set the time below to how frequently you wanna update 
          setTimeout(() => this.fetchData(), 5000);
          //
        }   
    catch (error) {console.log(error);}
  }
```